# Git (LFS): error (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

Prerequisites:

- GitLab Self-Hosted via AWS EC2
- GitLFS v3.3.0 installed on both server/client
- Trying to commit/push a small bunches of .obj files with **success**
- Trying to commit/push a big folder of .obj files — **no success**

Getting this error in terminal

```
! [remote rejected]   v0.0.1/lfs/objs_2 -> v0.0.1/lfs/objs_2 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to "server.ip.here:gitlab-group-name/repo-name.git"
```

Also, seeing a 401 error in gitlab-tail.log, which is weird as **everything works** as intended if I use the same key to push the same files, but **10-15 at a time**.

*P.S. I always push LFS-related commits via `--no-verify` flag, as I get another error otherwise. Not sure if it is related to the question.*

Comment: Is there any other information you can share? The pre-receive hook is a server-side hook that determines whether the server will accept a given push; it's most often used to enforce permissions on a repo or branch, but it could also be doing other things here.

Comment: @JimRedmond GitLab instance is sort of "fresh", installed couple weeks ago. After that I never touched it, just installed git-lfs on my EC2 instance over ssh via terminal. I don't see any hooks on GitLab dashboard and never added manually. I assume there may be some sort of "maximum commit size" or "files amount" rules, but I've found out where to find and adjust it.

P.S. It's a pain to push 5000 files.. 12 at a time.. manually :)

Comment: Just because GitLFS is installed on the server OS it doesn't mean it's enabled in GitLab... go through the settings (see the manual) and make sure it's enabled.

Comment: @fredrik it enabled. Moreover, I couldn't push small commits with LFS files, if it is disabled, I suppose.

Comment: That hook would only trigger if they aren't being tracked by GitLFS - so you've probably missed something in the setup or configuration of the repo (not on the server) or the files were already committed to the repo before GitLFS was added

Comment: @fredrik I still don't get your point. If the problem happens due to the files were already committed, then I'd face the problem even pushing small bunches of files. Or am I missing something?